# Is facebook's mobile app login form a WebView or a native mobile login UI?

Tags: authentication, mobile, webview, openid, identityserver4

I am implementing a native mobile app and I have an identity server that i use to achieve open id authentication.

I searched on internet for a way to authenticate users in my mobile app through a native UI but according to https://vimeo.com/171942749, resource owner flow is not recommended, and the more secure way is still open id and going through browser redirection.

So i was wondering if this applies also to the facebook app, is the login interface that we see in facebook app, a login web page loaded inside a customized webview (browser) or a native UI?